# different base href for links and images

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with all images and files uploaded in wwwroot and text data are being read from database.

I have created a folder in wwwroot naming "**mobile**" with different programming and design for mobile users. I want to display images from the root but keep the **base href** for links (anchors) start from **mobile/** folder.

I have tried changing the src of images using javascript but obviously it fails because the src of images does not have **mobile/** in url when I set `<base href="mobile/">`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(img).each(function(){
     $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace("mobile/","");
  })
})
```

So how should I manage it? is there a way to make difference between images and anchors?

Answer (score 0):

Apply root-based urls to the images (or anything that isn't an anchor); the base url doesn't get applied on these, like eg.:

```
<img src="/images/image1.jpg" />
```

and use the base url for your anchors.